# Best ways to handle the Connection Interface

Tags: perl, design-patterns

We are using OOP perl as a programming languge to design this framework, so this algo-like code is in Perl.

We are developing an automation framework in OOP Perl for an end-point device. This end-point device provides a HTTP, Telnet and SSH interface to execute the certain set of commands. For simplicity, we can assume that all commands are supported by all the three connection interfaces, generating the same output for a given command.

A function is written in the respective Connection class to handle a specific command.
e.g.

```
sub getVersion {
    return $http->sendCommand('version');
    }
```

But the current implementation of calling such function is little but different. Suppose, we would like to call the getVersion function, then it will be called something like this.

```
$device->getVersion(); //This is called through device object rather than connection object.
```

since this function is not defined in the device class, AUTOLOAD is called. In the Device class, AUTOLOAD is implemented like this

```
sub AUTOLOAD {
  my $connection = $device->getConnection();
  return $connection->$methodName (..); // when called for getVersion, $methodName will become the "getVersion"
  }
```

Please let me know if this is a good practice to implement it or should I modify it to remove the AUTOLOAD by implementing a function for each command in the device class, something like:

```
sub getVersion {
    my $connection = $device->getConnection();
    return $connection->getVersion();
}
```

We have 150+ such commands available through all the three interfaces (HTTP, Telnet, SSH).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`Class::Delegator`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class%3a%3aDelegator) is a good fit for a cleaner implementation. You could probably design a class that is the root behavior, say `Connected`, which defines how to get a connection.

```
{   package Connected;
    use Modern::Perl;

    sub getConnection { 
        ...
    }
}
{   package ConnectedObject;
    use Modern::Perl;
    use parent 'Connected';

    use Class::Delegator 
        send => [ 'getVersion'
                , 'obliterateAllLifeforms'
                , ... 
                ]
        to   => 'getConnection'
        ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! I want to really avoid the use of AUTOLOAD. I understand, it's not a good practice to use it. Since, I didn't have time, so I used it. Now I am re-factoring the code, so thinking to implement in better way by skipping AUTOLOAD.

Comment: @rpg `AUTOLOAD` is a *tool*. But you're probably right not to base an infrastructure on it. `AUTOLOAD` just suffers from the too-many-wizards problem. It was useful in a spreadsheet automation interface I had to make things like `$sheet->A5 + $sheet->C4` and not have to code for every cell name, but the more I came up with uses for `AUTOLOAD`, the more I wanted to encapsulate it in modules for the behavior, and as a result install `AUTOLOAD` handlers from a semi-blind stance of an exporter, I designed an AL integration pattern, but never fully coded it--because it just got too complex.

Comment: as you said that Class::Delegator is a good fit for a cleaner implementation. But as I see that I need to write it for my 150+ such functions (send => , to=>). So just want to think of any drawback where AUTOLOAD will really not work. Because with Class::Delegation, it seems that we need to add a new entry for any new method which we will be going to add. Please help me to understand on this!

Comment: @rpg, if you only want to send the method calls to the connection attribute, then you only have to write the *names* of the 150+ methods to send them there. Thus, you have specification==unlike `AUTOLOAD`. One thing about AUTOLOAD is that it doesn't create the method in the correct place. `$obj->can( 'getVersion' )` will fail. So, in my latter years of using AL, I overrode `can` and created `_can_work` to handle the creation of stubs that would do the job. (cont)

Comment: @rpg, You can always create a function that allows `Class::Delegate` to do it's work. `sub Class::Delegator::delegate {
    shift;
    my $package_name = shift;
    my @args         = @_;
    local $EVAL_ERROR;
    return if eval "{ package $package_name; Class::Delegator->import( \@args ); }; 1;";
    Carp::croak( $EVAL_ERROR ) if $EVAL_ERROR;
}`